# Sorting gridview in accordance to MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm implementing my first WPF application using the `MVVM` pattern.

According to the tutorial I'm following, it is a bad practice to have code in your code behind class.

Now I want to implement sorting of a `GridView` when you click on a column header.

The usual way to achieve this, is implementing a column click handler in your code behind class, which seems to be a code smell (see above).

**Is there a solution without using the code behind class?**

---

One way I can think of is to provide a `SortCommand : ICommand` in my viewmodel that does the sorting in the model. But I'm not sure if this is a good and clean solution.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sounds like you're on the right track to me, you're letting your view model control the data collection and then raising a property changed to let your view know to refresh.

Comment: @Paulie: I'm not sure, because the sorting has no relevance at all for the model. To me it seems to be only relevant for the view, so it could be considered a 'view only' information and could be misplaced in the model. But I'm beginner... Thanks for your opinion

Comment: There is nothing wrong in having code behind the view as long as it has no connection to model... If sorting can be done in view without actually bothering about data types and so on - why not?

Comment: I totally understand what you mean because I've only been doing WPF a month or so on a small project but my understanding is that your model is not a replacement for your Business layer, it is an encapsulation of Properties And Functionality for a view but is not aware of what the view is, your sorting might only be relevant for that view but do you envisage using your model in other places where sorting would not be needed? Again I'm a beginner too, so I might have mis-understood the concept.

Comment: An advice which could come in handy: don't take the approach "code-behind = evil". MVVM's purpose is NOT to eliminate code-behind, but to limit it and clearly separate your parts. Sorting a list has no sense in the model & ViewModel, if you sort it, it's only for the user's convenience, and it's a pure GUI functionality. Therefore, placing it in the code-behind won't make you kill MVVM. In fact, in my opinion you'll actually enhance it. Features coded in code-behind must be **purely GUI** ie. no data operations

Comment: It depends a bit on what you do with that information.  If it is truly a sort done for this View only, and you are not going to do anything else with it, you can do so in the code-behind.  However, if you plan on using for other purposes (for instance, using the same sort in another View connected to your VM, or saving the sort order between instances of your application), then doing that work in the ViewModel (not Model) makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the command approach.

Remember that the Model is your data, the ViewModel is an adaptor which makes the data available to the View, and the View is your GUI.